# Using the Lagrange interpolation formula to find a polynomial f with $f(-1)=-6, f(0)=2, ...$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

The exercise goes as follows:

*Use the Lagrange interpolation formula to find a polynomial $f$ with real coefficients such that $f$ has degree $\leq3$ and $f(-1)=-6, f(0)=2, f(1)=-2, f(2)=6$.*

So to start, I wrote down the formula $$f=\sum^n_{i=0}f(t_i)P_i$$
But I didn't manage to get much further than that. I understand that $P_i$ are polynomials of degree $i$, but I'm not sure how I can do anything with that information.

Comment: look please   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Answer (score 2):

Your data pairs $(x_i, f_i)$, $0\leq i\leq 3$ are $(-1, -6), (0, 2), (1, -2)$ and $(2, 6)$. The $3$-degree polynomial $P_3(x)$ that you would get using Lagrange's interpolation is $$P_3(x)=\sum_{i=0}^3f_iL_i(x)$$ where $$L_i(x)=\prod_{j=0\\ j\neq i}^3\dfrac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}$$ are the basis polynomials. For example, $$L_0(x)=\dfrac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{(-1)(-1-1)(-1-2)}.$$ Similarly find $L_1(x), L_2(x), L_3(x)$ and then calculate $P_3(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose an alternative way to solve the problem. Coefficients of Lagrange interpolation polynomial can be found if one uses a determinant form of Lagrange interpolation presented in "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", section "Lagrange interpolation" (you may check for concrete example in "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)"). General formula looks as follows
$$
f(x) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0       & f_0       & f_1       & \cdots & f_n       \\
        x^n     & x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x^{n-1} & x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots  & \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1       & 1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$

**EXAMPLE**

Let's consider your case: $f(-1) = -6$, $f(0) = 2$, and $f(2) = 6$. Previous equation should be written as
$$
f(x) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0       & -6       & 2       & 6       \\
        x^2     & (-1)^2   & 0^2     & 2^2     \\
        x       & -1       & 0       & 2       \\
        1       & 1        & 1       & 1       \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        (-1)^2   & 0^2     & 2^2     \\
        -1       & 0       & 2       \\
        1        & 1       & 1       \\
    \end{pmatrix}
} = 2 + 6 x - 2 x^2.
$$
Now it is easy to check that
$$
\begin{aligned}
    f(-1) &= 2 - 6 - 2(-1)^2 = -6,\\
    f(0)  &= 2 + 0 - 0 = 2,\\
    f(2)  &= 2 + 12 - 2\, (2)^2 = 6
\end{aligned}
$$